# Delay calling a function by a few seconds?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am have a problem with setTimeout and setInterval functions.
Here is my code:

```
if (a == true)
{
  setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
}
```

It does delay calling the function by 2 seconds however it calls it multiple times while I want to call it just once if the condition are met and with a delay of 2 seconds
I have used setInterval but I had similar problems with that

Comment: Letter case matters. Please make sure you use `setTimeout` not `SetTimeout`

Comment: You cannot use `function` as a variable name. It's a reserved keyword.

Comment: @connexo it refers to the function

Comment: When you only want to call it once then `setInterval` is definitely the wrong choice. Please include more relevant code because what you posted doesn't make the function run more than once on its own.

Comment: @ChrisG I am using p5js and this function is being called in the draw function which executes continuously each frame so I am guessing it has something to do with that

Comment: Yeah, draw() runs like 30 times per second. If you only want to run this once you need a variable to keep track of whether the setTimeout command was already called.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the condition is met multiple times, and you only want the first `true` evaluation of the condition to trigger the delayed function call. In that case, you just need to track whether or not it's already been run, and update it to `true` afterward:

```js
// In a shared scope so it can be modified inside the delayed function
var didRunWithDelay = false;

// Elsewhere
if (conditionWasMet && !didRunWithDelay) {
    didRunWithDelay = true;
    setTimeout(delayedFunction, 2000);
}

// Your function
function delayedFunction() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

If your condition can be `true` multiple times, the delayed function will be called each time. So you track, in a boolean, whether or not that condition has triggered the `setTimeout` already. If not, you call it, otherwise skip it.

Comment: This solution is basically fine but you need to fix the code; a) `didRunWithDelay = true;` b) it needs to be set in the // Elsewhere part

Answer (score -1):

The function `setTimeout()` takes as parameter a function followed by a number that corresponds to the time in milliseconds after which the function will be executed.

It is also important to keep in mind that the `setTimeout()` function executes asynchronously, i.e. the functions called afterwards will be called directly and not after the time passed in parameter has elapsed.

```
setTimeout(() => {console.log("this is the first message")}, 5000);
setTimeout(() => {console.log("this is the second message")}, 3000);
```

In this example, the second message will be displayed 2 seconds (2000ms) before the first!

It is possible to pass as parameter either reference to a function via its name and parameters or to use an annonymous function via writing `() => { code here }`.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, but this does not solve the OP's problem. The `setTimeout` call is incidental here, OP's question is actually about only calling a function once despite the function containing the call running again and again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).